# Change URL from www.xyz.com/abc.php to www.xyz.com/abc

Tags: php, .htaccess

If my URL is http://www.example.com/abc.php then it should open http://www.example.com/abc

I need to do only for one page not for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^abc$ abc.php [L]

you can change ^abc with any name which suites your requirement and this change will apply for only abc.php

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You've to create a .htaccess file with that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(abc)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

If you want to see more about .htaccess you can check this link:

https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: Quote: "I need to do only for one page not for others."

Comment: @Quentin ... He edit his question while I was answering.

Comment: @vishu My last update should work only for your abc.php page.

Answer (score 0):

> You can tried file .htaccess in fodder root of your websites.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "$1.php"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!